# Need To combine two columns Date and Time in mysql table and find the difference with current date and time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, time

Actually i need to list out the data which is not exceeds 24 hours from the mail Date and Time.

I have stored the Mail Date and Mail Time in 2 different columns in database.

Please give your valid inputs from the below query I wrote,

```
      $CTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
      //getting the 24 hours back time
      $Btime = $CTime - 86400;

      $listingInvoice = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *, (CONCAT(MailDate, MailTime)) AS MailDT FROM approved WHERE JobStatus='MailedToClient' && MailDT > '$Btime'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the date and time taken from different columns of database and find the value i.e., not exceed 24 hrs from the current time.

```
      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

      //getting the current date and time...
      $CTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

      //convert to string the current date and time...
      $CSTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

      //Minus the 86400(value of 24 Hrs in seconds) in the converted date and time string
      $BStime = $CSTime - 86400;

      //getting the value of date and time before 24 Hrs...
      $BTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $BStime);

      //Now the query is...
      $reject = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM approved WHERE JobStatus='MailToClient' && MailDateTime BETWEEN '$BTime' AND '$CTime'");
      $row = mysqli_num_rows($reject);
      if ($row == '0')
      {
        echo "No Jobs Mails SENT for the Last 24 Hrs";
      }
      else
      {
        ....
      }
```